# Linking ClassName to file in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, gatsby

I have a ClassName="logo" that I would like to use to style the logo in the component file. Having no joy thus far. Am I missing something here?

Index file, location the footer will display:

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "../components/header"
import Hero from "../components/hero"
import Footer from "../components/footer"

export default () => (
  <>  
    <Footer></Footer>
  </>
)
```

Footer css file:

```
@import "../styles/global.scss";

.footer {
  background-color: $black;
  color: $white;
  height: 230px;
  text-align: center;

  .logo {
  height: 20px;
  }
}
```

Footer.js file:

```
import React from "react"
import footerStyles from "./footer.module.scss"

export default ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <div className={footerStyles.footer}>
      <img className="logo" src="/svgs/logo_white.svg" alt="logo text"></img>
    </div>{children}</div> 
  </>
)
```

Comment: Why are you not passing the className as className={footerStyles.logo} to your <img /> tag?
And are you able to see the styles for footer class in your elements by  inspecting them?